# Invalid SSL certificate on Steam with Wine

Tags: 16.04, wine, steam, ssl

Steam webpage doesn't show (or showing poorly, if it's possible) when I run it from Wine. The problem doesn't occur with native Linux install, and this is the first time I experienced this issue.

What did I do is running Steam with `-no-cef-sandbox` argument on the terminal, so the web helper can run.

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 1):

Install the 32-bit `libldap` and `openssl` libraries:

```
sudo apt install libldap-2.4-2:i386 openssl:i386
```

No need to add the `-no-cef-sandbox`.

It only worked after reboot and deleting the **wineprefix** folder.

Comment: Both packages are not found in repository. Any exact name of it?

Comment: As I've said, those are the packages names in Manjaro Linux, you should search for these packages in some Ubuntu PPA.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by installing Winetricks....

Now Steam installs games and no `Invalid SSL certificate` message.

Comment: Can you explain what steps you followed?

Comment: Hi Stephen,  just installed Winetricks through Synaptic. Best